# Golang RoundTripper delivers empty reply

Tags: http, go, reverse-proxy

I built a small reverse proxy forwarding requests to another port on the same machine and delivering the result back to the caller.

In my case the result of the service is a simple html page containing links. Since the reverse proxy is running on a different port than the service I have to adjust the links. I tried to do so using a custom implementation of Transport:

```
type transport struct {
    http.RoundTripper
}

func (t *transport) RoundTrip(req *http.Request) (resp *http.Response, err error) {
    resp, err = t.RoundTripper.RoundTrip(req)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    err = resp.Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // This works
    b = bytes.Replace(b, []byte("http://localhost:5000"), []byte("http://localhost:8080"), -1)

   // This doesn't
    b = bytes.Replace(b, []byte("api"), []byte("auth-api"), -1)

    resp.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewReader(b))
    resp.ContentLength = int64(len(b))

    return resp, nil
}
```

This is how I initialize the reverse proxy in the request handler:

```
proxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(target)
proxy.Transport = &transport{http.DefaultTransport}
proxy.ServeHTTP(res, req)
```

The first replacement in my code works. But the seconds leads to several additional calls of the client (recognized through multiple hits of the breakpoint) and no result:

```
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

If I uncomment

```
b = bytes.Replace(b, []byte("api"), []byte("auth-api"), -1)
```

everything works just fine and the hostname gets replaced as expected. I tried debugging so hard, but wasn't able to find out whats wrong. If I save the body to a file after the replace has been done everything seems to be just fine and the prefix  gets exchanged as well. It simply fails in delivering it through the response.

Comment: The multiple calls to the client is definitely suspicious - sounds like you're hitting some redirects or something with the manipulated body. I would log the body after you've done your replaces and check to make sure it's doing what you expect - maybe it's finding more instances of `api` in the body than you had expected?

Comment: As I wrote I save the result of the replacement to a file before going on with the request and the content looks like what I expected.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitively not a problem of my code.
I created a minimal working example which is completely independent and could be tested by anyone of you. If you comment in line 37 (the second replacement) port 8080 (the reverse proxy) will not be respond anymore.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httputil"
    "net/url"
)

type transport struct {
    http.RoundTripper
}

func (t *transport) RoundTrip(req *http.Request) (resp *http.Response, err error) {
    resp, err = t.RoundTripper.RoundTrip(req)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    err = resp.Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // This works
    b = bytes.Replace(b, []byte("localhost:5000"), []byte("localhost:8080"), -1)

    // This doesn't
    // b = bytes.Replace(b, []byte("api"), []byte("auth-api"), -1)

    reader := bytes.NewReader(b)
    closer := ioutil.NopCloser(reader)
    body := closer
    resp.Body = body
    resp.ContentLength = int64(len(b))

    return resp, nil
}

func main() {
    infoPageServer := http.NewServeMux()
    infoPageServer.HandleFunc("/", serveHTML)

    reverseProxy := http.NewServeMux()
    reverseProxy.HandleFunc("/", serveProxy)

    // Running Info Page Server
    go func() {
        log.Println("Starting Info Page service on port 5000")
        http.ListenAndServe(":5000", infoPageServer)
    }()

    // Running Reverse Proxy Server
    log.Println("Starting Reverse Proxy service on port 8080")
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", reverseProxy)
}

func serveHTML(resp http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    const html = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <title>Info Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <pre>http://localhost:5000/api/</pre>
  </body>
</html>`
    fmt.Fprint(resp, html)
}

func serveProxy(resp http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    target, err := url.Parse("http://localhost:5000")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    proxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(target)
    proxy.Transport = &transport{http.DefaultTransport}
    proxy.ServeHTTP(resp, req)
}
```